# App engine shutting down and starting up after ~10 minutes

Tags: google-app-engine, restart

For some reason app engine shuts down sometimes (so far it has happened 3 times on different dates) and then starts up after 10 minutes (manually stopping and starting the instance takes ~1min, so this seems very long).

There are no errors before or other logs that indicate a cause for the shutdown (there's neither an ah/stop that comes before the shutdown).

The application is run in manual scaling mode with 1 instance on standard app engine. The application is most of the time "idle" (it does run things but doesn't receive requests.) The runtime is java11.

What could be the reason?

[logs before shutdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvQPw.png)

```
2021-06-21 23:45:25.372 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:45:25.371929 Quitting on terminated signal
Default
2021-06-21 23:45:25.373 EDT
I0622 03:45:25.373024 24 statistician.cc:113] Statistics of class_prepare_time_micros: mean = 10.4196, stdev = 31.173, min = 2, max = 1046, samples = 3203
Default
2021-06-21 23:45:25.710 EDT
I0622 03:45:25.381978 1340 jvmti_agent.cc:222] Java VM termination
Default
2021-06-21 23:45:25.711 EDT
I0622 03:45:25.384263 29 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:99] Agent thread exited: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
Default
2021-06-21 23:45:25.711 EDT
I0622 03:45:25.387276 1340 worker.cc:113] Debugger threads terminated
Default
2021-06-21 23:45:25.712 EDT
I0622 03:45:25.387315 1340 jvmti_agent.cc:236] JvmtiAgent::JvmtiOnVMDeath cleanup time: 5348 microseconds
Default
2021-06-21 23:45:25.811 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:45:25.810839 Start program failed: termination triggered by nginx exit
Info
2021-06-21 23:54:58.069 EDT
GET
200
111 B
5.896 s
/_ah/start
```

[init logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxYlQ.png)

```
2021-06-21 23:45:25.372 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:45:25.371929 Quitting on terminated signal
Default
2021-06-21 23:45:25.811 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:45:25.810839 Start program failed: termination triggered by nginx exit
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:58.440 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:54:58.438391 Starting app
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:58.441 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:54:58.440653 Executing: /bin/sh -c exec serve /workspace/ingest.jar
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:58.445 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:54:58.445422 Waiting for network connection open. Subject:"app/invalid" Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:58.446 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:54:58.445915 Waiting for network connection open. Subject:"app/valid" Address:127.0.0.1:8081
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:58.483 EDT
[serve] 2021/06/22 03:54:58.482876 Serve started.
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:58.485 EDT
[serve] 2021/06/22 03:54:58.483776 Args: {runtimeLanguage:java runtimeName:java11 memoryMB:512 positional:[/workspace/ingest.jar]}
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:58.487 EDT
[serve] 2021/06/22 03:54:58.486069 Running /bin/sh -c exec java -agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so=--log_dir=/var/log -jar /workspace/ingest.jar
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:59.702 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:54:59.701720 Wait successful. Subject:"app/valid" Address:127.0.0.1:8081 Attempts:251 Elapsed:1.255602687s
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:59.702 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:54:59.701951 Starting nginx
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:59.711 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:54:59.710592 Waiting for network connection open. Subject:"nginx" Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Default
2021-06-21 23:54:59.753 EDT
[start] 2021/06/22 03:54:59.745519 Wait successful. Subject:"nginx" Address:127.0.0.1:8080 Attempts:5 Elapsed:33.709637ms
```

[an expanded init log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZa6r.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, my app (JVM 11) is configured with manual scaling and 1 instance and App Engine seems to periodically kill it for no apparent reason (this is not a memory issue). However my app is restarted in one or two minutes, but this is long enough for me to receive an incident notice for the uptime check I configured. I get the same 'Quitting on terminated signal' and 'Start program failed: termination triggered by nginx exit' logs.

Answer (score 0):

If no requests come in for a while, GAE will shut down. If you would like to keep your instances running, you have to consider to configure `min_idle_instances`. See [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref).

Comment: Thanks N.F. Added more details to clarify the question. (The instance is in manual scaling mode)